# Writing content to notepad with separator using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create notepad like this

```
100001|10001|1001|91|9942321400|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
100001|10001|1001|91|9942321400|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
100001|10001|1001|91|9942321400|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
100001|10001|1001|91|9942321400|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
100001|10001|1001|91|9942321400|MR|Hari|Q|PUBLIC|249 MUNDON ROAD|MALDON|FL|44|TN|NO_PROVINCE|600004|IN|M|27304|9942321400|test@test.com|nothing|COMMENTS|1|Southeast
```

am storing each and every value in string .

```
dim a string="100001"
dim b as string ="10001"
Dim c As String = "1001"
Dim d As String = "91"
Dim e As String = "MR"
Dim f As String = "Hari"
Dim g As String = "Q"
Dim h As String = "PUBLIC"
Dim i1 As String = "249 MUNDON ROAD"
```

for writing content to notepad am using this code:

```
sw.WriteLine(a & "|" & b & "|" & c & "|" & d & "|" & dumphone & "|" & e & "|" & f & "|" & g & "|" & h 
& "|" & i1)
```

but I am getting error. Please help me do this?

> Operator '+' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.EventArgs'

Comment: it is a variable in string datatype contain values like 9865016695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared a variable with the name 'e'. I'm guessing your code is running from within a method that handles an event (e.g., button1.click), and what you're actually getting is the variable 'e as System.EventArgs' added to every handler. Give your variables proper names that don't conflict with existing ones. I'm sure you're getting an error to this effect, like 'e is already declared as a parameter of this method'. That's certainly what I see in VS2003 upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that with the variable `e` you are referencing a string and not a `System.EventArgs` object?

Maybe you are defining the procedure in a method fired by an event and the variable is overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is not enough to reproduce your problem, but I strongly assume you are using this code inside a methods that acts as an event handler and thus has a parameter named `e` which is of type `EventArgs`.

---

The solution is to use other (and maybe more meaningfull) variable names that will not get overriden.

I also assume your `a`, `b`, `c` etc. are class members.
Despite the poor name, you can access them using e.g. `Me.c` instead of just `c` if this is the case.

---

BTW, I also recommend to use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) for the concatenating your string.

```
String.Join("|", a, b, c, d, dumphone, e, f, g, h, i1)
```

which is much easier to read than

```
a & "|" & b & "|" & c & "|" & d & "|" & dumphone & "|" & e & "|" & f & "|" & g & "|" & & "|" & i1
```

Comment: I think this is a compile time error, so no `stopping at the exception` ;) Anyway, I think your answer is correct.